# Find date with respect to maximum number of new cases in panda python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Covid3 = ("USA", country_grp['new_deaths'].max().loc['United States'] , " China", country_grp['new_deaths'].max().loc['China'] ," India", country_grp['new_deaths'].max().loc['India'])
#covid3.loc[filter]['data']
```

I am trying to find a data that the these countries had maximum cases. I want to know how i could retrieve that from my dataset

```
Country date new  deaths
Ghana   01/01/2020 1500
Senegal 01/05/2020 1800
Ghana   01/02/2020 1500
Senegal 01/03/2020 1800
Canada   02/02/2020 500
Vietnam   01/30/2020 5000
```

**Output should be**

> The new deaths for each of the three countries are ('multiple country', maximum new deaths,and associated date

Comment: Please post sample data and expected outcome

Comment: `country_grp['new_deaths'].max().idxmax()`?

Comment: It gave me country only and i do need max deaths and the date that happened as well.

Comment: @Simon posted my data. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by sorting and then choosing the first entry. The code is as follows:

```
df.sort_values(by=["new_deaths"], ascending=False, ignore_index=True).loc[0, "date"]
```

The output is:

```
'01/30/2020'
```

---

If you would like to access the entire entry, the code is:

```
df.sort_values(by=["new_deaths"], ascending=False, ignore_index=True).loc[0]
```

The output is:

```
Country          Vietnam
date          01/30/2020
new_deaths          5000
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: i tried but it only gave me a date....I am not sure what did I miss